# How do I get my title to break and show ellipses without expanding tile size?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a responsive site that has tiles with titles and descriptions.  The issue i am having is when the screen size gets smaller the tiles get smaller and the title has less space.  When the size of the tile is hit and the text is supposed to get hidden and display an ellipses ... at the end.  instead what happens is the text increases the size of the entire tile but the tile is getting higher than what it should be able to get to.  Any suggestions on how to get the title to not wrap and add the ellipse without increasing the tile size?

I included an image on the tile where I noticed the problem and then My CSS and HTML for this page.

[image]

```css
/* Float four columns side by side (desktop view)*/

.column {
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex; */
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px
}

@media (min-width: 668px) {
  .column {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 425px;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .column {
    display: block;
  }
}

.tile-card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0006;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* 
.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
} */

.dash-description {
  width: 70%;
  height: 65%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00384f;
  /* padding-top: 11px; */
}

.tile-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 65%;
  /* padding-top: 15px; */
  float: left;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
}

.report-type {
  /* display: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.foot {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #4d4d4d;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* position: relative;
bottom: 0px; */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.linkTrail {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.linkTrail li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul.linkTrail li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

ul.linkTrail li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

ul.linkTrail li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "tahoma", Times, Serif;
}


/* Extra Large devices - 1025px and up will have 4 columns */

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col-extraLarge-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}


/* Large devices - 992px to 1024px will have 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .col-large-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/* Medium devices - 668px to 991px will have 2 columns */

@media (min-width: 668px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-medium-6 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Small devices - 667px and below will have 1 column */

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .col-small-12 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.article,
  div.welcome {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TileTemplate.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">​Bookings Trend</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">​Interactive dashboard that displays trends for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time.</div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Detailed KPIs</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">High level views of the business and where we stand against weekly target for major indicators such as bookings, funnel, inflow and closed/lost.​<br/>​ </div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>​
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Executive KPI Summary</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Companywide information and statistics dashboard with views of where we stand against weekly</div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Funnel Inflow Trends</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that shows trends in funnel inflow over time.​</div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">​
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Funnel Trends</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views of the funnel.​​<br/></div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Bookings Trends​​<br/></div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays trends from a Route to Market perspective for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and
            overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Funnel Trends</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views from a Route to Market perspective of the funnel. Including opportunity count and average selling price. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="tile-card">
        <div class="dash-title">Weekly Forecast Call</div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
          <div class="dash-description">Detailed view of current quarter and next quarter deal rollup by region with field calls.​<br/></div>
          <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>​​​<br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You will need to use JS or some sort of server-side language like PHP to accomplish this. If you are using PHP it's pretty easy to use `substr()`.

Comment: @disinfor is right. Also, since you're working with a responsive layout it would probably be easier to go the Javascript route. The equivalent function is substring() in JS.

Comment: when I added "position: absolute"  to .dash-title it almost fixed it but it sort of created another problem.  The ellipses shows up correctly and there isn't a line wrap but now the dash title, which is the whole blue bar, stretches the full width of the column it is in... it's width is set to 100% but I expected it to be 100% relative to the tile-card it is in and not the column width... not sure how to fix this either.

Comment: @MikeDurso you really can't do what you are trying to do, without truncating the text either prior with a server-side or after with JS. As Frank A pointed out, with a responsive layout those are really your options, as CSS alone can't address this. How are you generating each of your `column` divs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using a jQuery `each` method. You can switch out the `70` to any value you want.

If you want to make this even more responsive, you can wrap this in a `$(window).resize()` function and check to see how wide the browser window is and then not even run this if it's in mobile or tablet.

```js
// For each element with this class.
$('.dash-description').each(function() {
  // Set a variable equal to the text of the element.
  var inner_text = $(this).text();
  // Checks to see how long the original length is. If the text is shorter than the value of 70, then don't run this next part.
  if (inner_text.length > 70) {
    // Trims the lines from the text and then pulls the first 70 characters
    var new_text = $.trim(inner_text).substring(0, 70);
    // Swaps the original text with the new truncated text and adds the ellipses
    $(this).text(new_text + '...');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Float four columns side by side (desktop view)*/

.column {
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex; */
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px
}

@media (min-width: 668px) {
  .column {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 425px;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .column {
    display: block;
  }
}

.tile-card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0006;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* 
.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
} */

.dash-description {
  width: 70%;
  height: 65%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00384f;
  /* padding-top: 11px; */
}

.tile-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 65%;
  /* padding-top: 15px; */
  float: left;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
}

.report-type {
  /* display: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.foot {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #4d4d4d;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* position: relative;
bottom: 0px; */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.linkTrail {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.linkTrail li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul.linkTrail li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

ul.linkTrail li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

ul.linkTrail li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "tahoma", Times, Serif;
}


/* Extra Large devices - 1025px and up will have 4 columns */

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col-extraLarge-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}


/* Large devices - 992px to 1024px will have 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .col-large-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/* Medium devices - 668px to 991px will have 2 columns */

@media (min-width: 668px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-medium-6 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Small devices - 667px and below will have 1 column */

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .col-small-12 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.article,
  div.welcome {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">​Bookings Trend</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">​Interactive dashboard that displays trends for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time.</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Detailed KPIs</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">High level views of the business and where we stand against weekly target for major indicators such as bookings, funnel, inflow and closed/lost.</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Executive KPI Summary</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Companywide information and statistics dashboard with views of where we stand against weekly</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Funnel Inflow Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that shows trends in funnel inflow over time.</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">​
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Funnel Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views of the funnel.</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Bookings Trends​​<br/></div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays trends from a Route to Market perspective for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and
          overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Funnel Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views from a Route to Market perspective of the funnel. Including opportunity count and average selling price. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Weekly Forecast Call</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Detailed view of current quarter and next quarter deal rollup by region with field calls.​<br/></div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's the version with the resize event included:

```js
// New function. Arguments are the element and the window width.
function wpso_08012019_truncate_text(element, window_width) {
  // Loop through the passed elements.
  element.each(function() {
    // Set a var for the element's text.
    var inner_text = $(this).text();
    // Set a data attribute on the element with the original text. We'll need this later.
    $(this).attr('data-original', inner_text);
    // If the character count of the text is longer than this value (70), then do this next stuff.
    if (inner_text.length > 70) {
      // Set a new var with the text truncated to a set character count (70).
      var new_text = $.trim(inner_text).substring(0, 70);
      // Set the text of the element to the truncated text plus the ellipses
      $(this).text(new_text + '...');
    }

    // If the window width is less than this, run this.
    if (window_width < 768) {
      // Set the text of the element to it's original text from the data-attribute we added earlier. Smart.
      $(this).text($(this).data('original'));
    }

  });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  // On resize set the var for the window width
  var window_width = $(window).width();
  // Run the function on resize passing in the element and the window width.
  wpso_08012019_truncate_text($('.dash-description'), window_width)

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Trigger the window resize event on document ready.
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
/* Float four columns side by side (desktop view)*/

.column {
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex; */
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px
}

@media (min-width: 668px) {
  .column {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 425px;
    min-width: 175px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .column {
    display: block;
  }
}

.tile-card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0006;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* 
.dash-title {
  background-color: #00A0D3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00A0D3;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
} */

.dash-description {
  width: 70%;
  height: 65%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00384f;
  /* padding-top: 11px; */
}

.tile-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 65%;
  /* padding-top: 15px; */
  float: left;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
}

.report-type {
  /* display: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.foot {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #4d4d4d;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* position: relative;
bottom: 0px; */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.linkTrail {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.linkTrail li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul.linkTrail li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

ul.linkTrail li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

ul.linkTrail li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "tahoma", Times, Serif;
}


/* Extra Large devices - 1025px and up will have 4 columns */

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col-extraLarge-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}


/* Large devices - 992px to 1024px will have 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .col-large-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/* Medium devices - 668px to 991px will have 2 columns */

@media (min-width: 668px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-medium-6 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Small devices - 667px and below will have 1 column */

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .col-small-12 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.article,
  div.welcome {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Bookings Trend</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays trends for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time.</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Detailed KPIs</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">High level views of the business and where we stand against weekly target for major indicators such as bookings, funnel, inflow and closed/lost.<br /></div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Executive KPI Summary</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Companywide information and statistics dashboard with views of where we stand against weekly</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Funnel Inflow Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that shows trends in funnel inflow over time.​</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Funnel Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views of the funnel.<br /></div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Bookings Trends<br /></div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays trends from a Route to Market perspective for software &amp; product bookings, deal counts, average selling prices and discounts over time. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and
          overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Route To Market Funnel Trends</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Interactive dashboard that displays historical views from a Route to Market perspective of the funnel. Including opportunity count and average selling price. This view includes both a hierarchical view (single-crediting) and overlay view (multi-crediting).</div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="column col-extraLarge-3 col-large-4 col-medium-6 col-small-12">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="tile-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Weekly Forecast Call</div>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <img class="tile-icon" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/Legal.png" alt="" />
        <div class="dash-description">Detailed view of current quarter and next quarter deal rollup by region with field calls.<br /></div>
        <img class="report-type" src="/sites/bic/PublishingImages/power-bi.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle to play with the resize version:

https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/9fe3758p/12/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to have fixed height tile and if the length of content increases some defined length you need to show '...'?

It can be done with Javascript and If you're using Angular then you can use pipe which can be reused.

**Javascript approach**
Assume you're having your data in the array

```
var data =[{des:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'},{des:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'}];
let requiredLength =45;

data.map(e=>e['des']=`${e['des'].substr(0,requiredLength)}...`);
```

**Angular Approach**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.des | substr:45}}</div>
```

Create angular pipe having name substr, which can be used in entire application

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'substr'
})
export class SubstrPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string:length:number) {

   return `${value.substr(0, length)}...`;

  }
```

Comment: There is no Angular tag on this question, so it's probably safe to assume that Angular isn't being used. A vanilla JS answer or PHP answer would be much better. Also, my guess that the data isn't in an array.

Comment: @disinfor that's the reason I provided both the approaches JavaScript and Angular. If the data is not in array, it's better to push into array and he can repeat the HTML using jQuery, which means no repeat of same html code